# Image component multiplication without using loops in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I have two [RGB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RGB_color_model) images, let's say `A` and `B`. Both have equal sizes with the dimension '(x,y,3)'. How do I multiply both images such that we take the dot product at every location and the result will be a matrix of size '(x,y) '?

For example, 'A(1,1,:)*transpose(B(1,1,:))'. With loops it is very slow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use MATLAB's inbuilt function [`dot`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/dot.html). So to take the dot product along the third dimension, use

```
C=dot(A,B,3);
```